# How to convert on-surface curve to seam?

Tags: mesh, uv, bezier-curves

I have a cylinder-like surface and a mirrored bezier curve shrinkwrapped onto it.
I'd like to use the curve as a seam for UV mapping, actually for pattern making purposes.
How can I create from the curve a (possibly easily selectable) edge loop on the cylinder?

[image]

Comment: you say 'pattern cutting' Is that  in the flat? Could you elaborate a bit more on the intended use?

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way to do it.

- adjust the shrinkwrap modifier so that the curve is entirely just above the surface.
- apply the mirror modifier.  You may want to make a backup copy of the curve before you do this.
- In object mode select first the curve and then the cylinder.
- Go to edit mode
- *Knife Project*. You may want to make a backup copy of the cylinder before you do this.  You can find *Knife Project* in the *Mesh* menu; or search for it with the <kbd>F3</kbd> search.

This will create edges on the cylinder that match the curve.  You can now mark those edges as seams. (Select the new edges, Ctrl–E to bring up the edge menu and select *Mark Seams*)

EDIT: Here's one way to ensure a precise match to a mirrored curve.

If you're mirroring, the original curve probably lies entirely one side of one of the axes.  Meanwhile the cylinder's length is parallel to another  In this example, the X and Z axes:

[image: Cylinder with curve all on one side of the X axis]

To obtain symmetry, knife project twice.  The first projection is from the orthogonal view along the 3rd axis, with the positive direction coming out of the screen.  In the example, that's the Front view.  The second projection is from, the orthogonal view along the 3rd axis, with the negative direction coming out of the screen.  In the example, that's the Back view.

Here's the example with the curve hidden showing a view of the cylinder after the two knife projections:

[image: After the knife projections]

There are cases this won't work for, but for the vast range of curves that are meant to be mirrored it should work well.

Comment: oh so they have also reimplemented the former way to use the knife project. Edit: no, it works this way only for curves, I didn't know you could cut with curve + there's a kind of inconsistency here

Comment: Your method creates nice edge loops but it has a downside. It creates edges on the surface closest to me, not on the one that is closest to the curve. I assume this is related to the way the tool works ("Keep in mind that Knife Project works from the current view’s perspective.") This gives incorrect result with a closed surface and a closed curve.

Comment: @kkeri you're right; knife project doesn't do what you want.  I'll give it some more thought.

Comment: The curve is mirrored, so you only have to work on half, and orthogonal knife-projection towards the mirror plane should be just fine? (mirroring the cylinder, too, if necessary)

Comment: @RobinBetts good point, I have to work with mirrored shapes. I tried out your idea and it works well on this example, however for more complex shapes it yields fuzzy edges near the tangent. I need high quality output, so may be knife project is not the right tool to achieve it.

Comment: @kkeri have you tried playing with the offset value of the shrinkwrap or not using a shrinkwrap but having the curve stand off the object?

Comment: @MartyFouts no, in the meantime I found a completely different solution, see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Finally I figured out how to solve my problem. My solution gives exact seams and it doesn't assume that the curve or the cylinder is mirrored.

- Convert the curve to a mesh, this will also apply all modifiers.
- Add a skin modifier to the curve.
- In edit mode select all vertices of the curve.
- Set *mean radius Y* to 0 and set *mean radius X* to an appropriate value to get a ring that intersects the cylinder in a single loop.
- If the ring leans on the cylinder surface, mark another vertex as root until you get a good result, similar to the screenshot below.

[image: Skin modifier]

- Now add a boolean *difference* modifier to the cylinder and select the curve in the *object* field.
- Apply the boolean modifier.

The resulting edge loop may need some cleanup but it is precise and independent of the current view.

[image: Final result]

Comment: a bit fiddly for finding the starting point, but a nice approach.